# New model object through an association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

I thought it was possible to create a new model object through an association.

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :basket
end

class Basket < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :order
end

order = Order.new()
basket = order.basket.new() # NoMethodError: undefined method `new' for nil:NilClass
```

Comment: For information: In Ruby the empty parentheses on `new` are generally omitted i.e. `Order.new`.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

It is, but your syntax is a little wrong:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :basket
end

class Basket < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :order
end

order = Order.new()
basket = order.create_basket()
```

Use `build_basket` if you don't want to save the basket immediately; if the relationship is `has_many :baskets` instead, use `order.baskets.create()` and `order.baskets.build()`

Comment: Thanks Chris for your reply, out of interest i tried basket = order.basket.new() when the relationship is has_many :baskets, and it worked fine. Its all very confusing.

Comment: It may work, but I'm not sure if order.basket collection will contain your newly created object, which means you can save `order` and have all child objects autosaved and referenced to `order` (without specifying it in parameters).