# Activerecord-association: create new object (find class)

Tags: php, phpactiverecord

I have an model with a relation, and I want to instantiate a new object of the relations type.

> Example: A person has a company, and I have a person-object: now I
>   want to create a company-object.

The class of the companyobject is defined in the relation, so I don't think I should need to 'know' that class, but I should be able to ask the person-object to provide me with a new instance of type company? But I don't know how.

This is -I think- the same question as [New model object through an association](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3821387/new-model-object-through-an-association) , but I'm using [PHPActiveRecord](http://www.phpactiverecord.org), and not the ruby one.

---

Reason behind this: I have an abstract superclass `person`, and two children have their own relation with a type of company object. I need to be able to instantiate the correct class in the abstract person.

A workaround is to get it directly from the `static $has_one` array:

```
$class   = $this::$has_one[1]['class_name'];
$company = new $class;
```

the hardcoded number can of course be eliminated by searching for the association-name in the array, but that's still quite ugly.

---

If there is anyone who knows how this is implemented in Ruby, and how the phpactiverecord implementation differs, I might get some Ideas from there?

---

Some testing has revealed that although the "search my classname in an array" looks kinda weird, it does not have any impact on performance, and in use it is functional enough.

Comment: @charles: phpactiverecord is a specific library, so the tag is actually usefull. If you think it is overkill, remove the activerecordtag and not the one that describes what library I use

Comment: Not sure if this helps but I was reading about the Reflections class. http://php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php. It checks classes and methods against all sorts of possibilities. This may help you out.

Comment: Sadly I don't think it'll help: The object isn't made at the time of writing, this is something the lib does for you, still thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also use `build_association()` in the relationship classes. 
Simplest way to use it is through the Model's __call, i.e. if your relation is something like `$person->company`, then you could instantiate the company with 
`$company = $person->build_company()`

Note that this will NOT also make the "connection" between your objects (`$person->company` will not be set). 
Alternatively, instead of `build_company()`, you can use `create_company()`, which will *save a new record and link it* to $person

Comment: Wait wut?! This is kinda what I was looking for?! lemme test :)

Comment: Yea I know :) You're welcome. 
Unfortunately those kind of calls aren't covered in the documentation

Comment: Apparently this works only with has_one? Any idea what should be similar function with has_many?

Comment: It should also work with has_many, as build_association() and create_association() are functions of the base AbstractRelationship class (actually reimplemented in HasMany, see http://www.phpactiverecord.org/docs/ActiveRecord/HasMany). I haven't tested tho

Answer (score 0):

> <s>I'm currently using below solution. It's an actual solution, instead
>   of the `$has_one[1]` hack I mentioned in the question. If there is a
>   method in phpactiverecord I'm going to feel very silly exposing
>   msyelf.  But please, prove me silly so I don't need to use this
>   solution :D</s>
>
> I am silly. Below functionality is implemented by the create_associationname call, as answered by @Bogdan_D

---

Two functions are added. You should probably add them in the `\ActiveRecord\Model` class. In my case there is a class between our classes and that model that contains extra functionality like this, so I put it there.

These are the 2 functions:

- `public function findClassByAssociation($associationName)`

  - Called with the name of the association you are looking for.
  - Checks three static vars (`has_many`,`belongs_to` and `has_one`) for the association
  - calls `findClassFromArray` if an association is found.
  - from the person/company example: `$person->findClassByAssociation('company');`
- `private function findClassFromArray($associationName,$associationArray)`

  - Just a worker-function that tries to match the name.

Source:

```
/**
 * Find the classname of an explicitly defined 
 * association (has_one, has_many, belongs_to). 
 * Unsure if this works for standard associations 
 * without specific mention of the class_name, but I suppose it doesn't!
 * @todo Check if works without an explicitly set 'class_name', if not: is this even possible (namespacing?)
 * @todo Support for 'through' associations.
 * @param String $associationName the association you want to find the class for
 * @return mixed String|false if an association is found, return the class name (with namespace!), else return false
 * @see findClassFromArray 
 */
public function findClassByAssociation($associationName){
    //$class = $this::$has_one[1]['class_name'];
    $that = get_called_class();
    if(isset($that::$has_many)){
        $cl = $this->findClassFromArray($associationName,$that::$has_many);
        if($cl){return $cl;}
    }
    if(isset($that::$belongs_to)){
        $cl = $this->findClassFromArray($associationName,$that::$belongs_to);
        if($cl){return $cl;}
    }
    if(isset($that::$has_one)){
        $cl = $this->findClassFromArray($associationName,$that::$has_one);
        if($cl){return $cl;}
    }
    return false;
}

/**
 * Find a class in a php-activerecord "association-array". It probably should have a specifically defined class name!
 * @todo check if works without explicitly set 'class_name', and if not find it like standard
 * @param String $associationName 
 * @param Array[] $associationArray phpactiverecord array with associations (like has_many)
 * @return mixed String|false if an association is found, return the class name, else return false
 * @see findClassFromArray
 */
private function findClassFromArray($associationName,$associationArray){
    if(is_array($associationArray)){
        foreach($associationArray as $association){
            if($association['0'] === $associationName){
                return $association['class_name'];
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In PHPActiveRecord, you have access to the relations array.  The relation should have a name an you **NEED TO KNOW THE NAME OF THE RELATIONSHIP/ASSOCIATION YOU WANT**.  It doesn't need to be the classname, but the classname of the Model you're relating to should be explicitly indicated in the relation.  Just a basic example without error checking or gritty relationship db details like linking table or foreign key column name:

```
class Person extends ActiveRecord\Model {
    static $belongs_to = array(
                       array('company',
                                 'class_name' => 'SomeCompanyClass')
                                 );
    //general function get a classname from a relationship
    public static function getClassNameFromRelationship($relationshipName)       
       foreach(self::$belongs_to as $relationship){
          //the first element in all relationships is it's name
          if($relationship[0] == $relationshipName){
             $className = null;
                if(isset($relationship['class_name'])){
                  $className = $relationship['class_name'];
                }else{
                  // if no classname specified explicitly,
                  // assume the clasename is the relationship name
                  // with first letter capitalized
                  $className = ucfirst($relationship);
                }
                return $className               
            }
        }   
        return null;
     }
}
```

To with this function, if you have a person object and want an object defined by the 'company' relationship  use:

```
$className = $person::getClassNameFromRelationship('company');
$company = new $className();
```

Comment: You are aware that I am talking about "phpactiverecord", a library (linked in the question), rather then a complete home-build framework? While this might be a valid tip if you are building from scratch, this is not really what the question is about... sorry..

Comment: @Nanne I tweaked my answer to use the PHPActiveRecord syntax exactly.  Hope this helps make my example clearer for your question.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you are trying to do here? It seems to me that this line: `self::$belongs_to[$relationshipName]['class_name'];` returns an error because company is not a key, it is a value. Also, the syntax for an assosiation is like this: `static $belongs_to = array(array('company','class_name' => 'class_name'));` You can either hardcode the index (a number) for the company (I provided a hack like that in the question: `$class   = $this::$belongs_to[0]['class_name'];`.) or you can look for the name, like in my answer? Both not really nice, so I was looking for a 3rd option.

Comment: @Nanne Sorry, missed that the relationship array doesn't use the relationship name as it's key/index as I've usually seen in other ORM's... would make more sense and provide faster access.  See above for the update to give you your answer.

Comment: @Nanne, Forget it, I see from reading above you made the same choice as I did just now.  Yes, they should add it to PHPActiveRecord.  They should also move the relationship name to be the key in the array.

Comment: Well, I'm using my own sollution as its's more complete, but as you've got the only other answer and put in some work, you're getting the bonus :D